# JSON Array - How to show array in an array

Tags: arrays, json

apologies for the question, I am not a master of this.

I am trying to show the add address (RED Circle).
The rest above I can make it show but the Red one I encircled is like another array which I dont know how to.

```
out += "<tr><td><b>ADDRESS NAME: </b>" +
    arr[i].addresses.name +
    "</td><tr>";
    out += "<tr><td><b>ADDRESS: </b>" +
    arr[i].addresses.street + arr[i].city +
    "</td><tr>";
```

That's what I put and it is outputting "undefined".
Please help..
Thank you

[image]

Comment: `arr[i].addresses[0].street`. Though the fact that `addresses` is an array suggests that there could be several addresses, or even none at all. Take this into consideration, maybe your approach should be to iterate over them.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show how you iterate. However, the issue is that you didn't specify what item from addresses array do you want to use. For example if you need only the first one:

```
out += "<tr><td><b>ADDRESS NAME: </b>" +
    arr[i].addresses[0].name +
    "</td><tr>";
    out += "<tr><td><b>ADDRESS: </b>" +
    arr[i].addresses[0].street + arr[i].adresses[0].city +
    "</td><tr>";
```

If you want to show all items you need to iterate inside adresses Array also.

Comment: @mark-juni if my answer help to solve your issue could you mark it as Answer. Thanks